# How do i prevent my .done handler from being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JQuery expression where i push a button, get some HTML from the server and then append it to a DOM node in my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".addbutton").click(function () {
                var addbuttonNode = $(this);
                $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", { id: '@guid' })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        $(addbuttonNode).next().next().append(data);   //find better way of doing this  
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have multiple ".addButton" buttons on my web site. The problem im experiencing is that after multiple clicks on the buttons my .done handler is being called multiple times.

My guess is that i have a list of event handlers that are being executed, I cant understand where / why this is done or how I prevent it from happening.

Comment: If you store a jquery object in a var like "var addbuttonNode = $(this);", then you don't nedd to wrap it with jQuery when you're use the variable to access the element after .done().

Comment: There's not enough data in the question to provide a definitive answer. Could you make a MCVE?

Comment: You are attaching an event handler to a button So the event handler will be called as many times as you click on the button. Since you mentioned you clicked on button multiple times, your event handler is bound to be called multiple times and thus making multiple ajax requests and hence multiple done invocations..

Comment: Thats not possible @BalázsVarga ,  since the diffirent buttos probably give  diffirent answers, he will have to save the data with the button.

Comment: So, maybe you need to disable button while this is loading.

Comment: So do you expect each button to be only once clickable or what? If only once, then just use jQuery `.one()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not taht you do the request is done more then once rathern then it calls done after its done.. you can keep the state in data object::

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var posting = false;
    $(".addbutton").data("done", false).click(function () {
        var addbuttonNode = $(this);
        if (!addbuttonNode.data("done")) {
            addbuttonNode.data("done", true);
            $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", { id: '@guid' })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $(addbuttonNode).next().next().append(data);   
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check it for any request pending:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".addbutton").click(function () {
         // if any request pending, return {undefined}
         if ($.active) return;
         var addbuttonNode = $(this);
         $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", {
             id: '@guid'
         }).done(function (data) {
             // instead of .next().next()
             $(addbuttonNode).nextAll('selector').first().append(data); //find better way of doing this  
             // or .parent().find('selector')
         });
     });
 });
```

If you wish instead each button to be clickable only once, then use jQuery `.one()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".addbutton").one('click', function () {
         var addbuttonNode = $(this);
         $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", {
             id: '@guid'
         }).done(function (data) {
             // instead of .next().next()
             $(addbuttonNode).nextAll('selector').first().append(data); //find better way of doing this  
             // or .parent().find('selector')
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: But he have multiple buttons, with one active request all buttons will be disabled.

Comment: @HaSuKrOnOs Ya but this is how i understand the question. I could be wrong, quite unclear imo what is expected behaviour. If only one button must be disabled, then the logic is to check for any specific button data/class/whatever and set logic according to it

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
$(".addbutton").click(function () {
            var addbuttonNode = $(this);
            addbuttonNode.attr('disabled',true);
            $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", { id: '@guid' })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $(addbuttonNode).next().next().append(data);   //find better way of doing this  
                     addbuttonNode.attr('disabled',false);
                });
        });
```

Comment: This offers a visual solution rather then something what helps to prevent the problem.

Comment: Disabled element doesn't fire click events as far i know, so thats prevents the problem.

Comment: That's right but type in console : $(".addbutton").click(); and it will still fire

Answer (score -2):

Try to use bind, and unbind functions for the event handling. Then You can unbind the click function after it was executed once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addbutton").bind('click',function () {
            var addbuttonNode = $(this);
            $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", { id: '@guid' }).done(function (data) {
                addbuttonNode.next().next().append(data);
            });
            addbuttonNode.unbind('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another way of doing nearly the same, I think this should be better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addbutton").each(function(){
            $(this).bind('click',function () {
                $.post("/InteractiveApplications/GetQuizAnswer", { id: '@guid' }).done(function (data) {
                    addbuttonNode.next().next().append(data);
                });
                $(this).unbind('click');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I haven't tried it yet, but it should work, try it! :)

You can also set up a class or data attribute to check if the button was already clicked. You can then exit from the script like if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) { return; } or something...

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted, it clearly shows the theory, and the theory works. Maybe not the cleanest solution.. But defenately not a bad